# How do you access the OUTPUT clause of an UPDATE query from a VIEW in SQL Server / SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

The trick was to execute this SQL from the calling application.

I want to update the records in a table every time I select them from a view with something like a `select_dt`.

This update query does a lot of what I want to do, but I can't save it as a view and access it repeatedly. What is the best way to do this? Would it be a user-defined function?

```
UPDATE
    [etl_clk].[dbo].[p079]
SET 
    [select_dt] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OUTPUT 
    INSERTED.part_no
WHERE 
    [part_no] IN (SELECT TOP (3000)
                        part_no
                  FROM
                      [etl_clk].[dbo].[p079]
                  WHERE
                      [select_dt] IS NULL
                      OR [select_dt] < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 10)
                  ORDER BY 
                      CASE WHEN [scrape_dt] IS NULL THEN '1/1/1950' ELSE [scrape_dt] END ASC)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a stored procedure? That would allow you to return data as well as update records.

Comment: @SteveB I had one down that road but couldn't figure out how to access the results of a stored procedure (post execution) in a view.

Comment: Views are not allowed to mutate data, no matter how you try to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to update the records in a table every time I select them from a view with something like a select_dt.

You cannot update rows when you select from a view.  You could write a stored procedure that updates the rows and returns the results.  Something like:

```
create or alter procedure update_and_get_p079s
as
begin

UPDATE
    [etl_clk].[dbo].[p079]
SET 
    [select_dt] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
OUTPUT 
    INSERTED.part_no
WHERE 
    [part_no] in(   SELECT TOP (3000)
                        part_no
                    FROM
                        [etl_clk].[dbo].[p079] with (updlock)
                    WHERE
                        [select_dt] IS NULL
                        OR
                        [select_dt] < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 10)
                    ORDER BY 
                        CASE WHEN [scrape_dt] IS NULL THEN '1/1/1950' ELSE [scrape_dt] END ASC
                );
end
```

Comment: There's no way to access the results of the stored procedure (post execution) from a view?

Comment: You could mark the updated rows with some sort of unique ID and query that from a view, I suppose.  But why?

Comment: @NicholasCuster what are you calling there view from? Inside SQL or via a programming language?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I've added some new detail to the post. The process that uses these records will update information about them and then clear the 'select_dt'.

Comment: @SteveB The view will be accessed through linked table or pass-through query in MS Access.

Comment: You can try the UPDATE ... OUTPUT in a passthrough query.  It does return a result.

Comment: @NicholasCuster everything you described in your updated question can be done in one stored procedure. You don't need a view to do it. You can also schedule it to run as a scheduled task on the SQL itself as well. I have done similar and can provide some code if that sounds good to you.